# Wordpress pages shown based on geolocation of the user

Tags: geolocation, wordpress

We are building a wordpress site with a different set of pages for each country it serves. For example there is an "about us" page for mexico, then another one for Guatemala, and so on.
I need a plugin that will

- Show the respective page based on the users' ip address.
- Also show parts of the header and footer customized for each country (I will
  use widgets most likely).
- And then in case of error, a dropdown menu to change the country (ie the widgets and page shown)

Is there such a thing?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/geolocation

Comment: would love answer to this.